# Adding single quote to Snowflake variable in Javascript Stored Procedure

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add single quote around the string and assign it to variable in a Snowflake Stored Procedure. But the value is returning as DEFAULT_STR as is.

```
var DEFAULT_STR = 'UNKNOWN'

var VAL_LIST = 'EMP_ID'

VAL_LIST = VAL_LIST +" "+ "'`${DEFAULT_STR}`'" + ','+ '"SYSTEM"';
```

**Error Message:**

`SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 183 invalid identifier '"`${DEFAULT_STR}`"' At Snowflake.execute`

Please advise how I can achieve below expected output-

**Expected output:**

`'EMP_ID UNKNOWN, SYSTEM"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should give you the output you want:

```
VAL_LIST = "'" + VAL_LIST +" "+ DEFAULT_STR + "," + "SYSTEM'";
```

The output of VAL_LIST is:

```
'EMP_ID UNKNOWN,SYSTEM'
```

Comment: Thank you ! Added unwanted quotes and messed up :D

Answer (score 1):

try this, this may work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION str_test()
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  var DEFAULT_STR = 'UNKNOWN'
    var VAL_LIST = 'EMP_ID'
    VAL_LIST = "'" + VAL_LIST +" "+ DEFAULT_STR + ','+ 'SYSTEM"';
    return VAL_LIST;
    
$$
;

select str_test() as a from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation using `+` in JavaScript requires opening and closing the string repeatedly. It rapidly becomes unreadable. Imagine a 200-line SQL statement with replacements in various points.

Rather than concatenation, I highly recommend using JavaScript template literals. You can open and close the string with a back quote. It supports multi-line strings that way and you can add any variable or expression using the format `${myVariable}`

So your string would look like this:

```
VAL_LIST = `'${VAL_LIST} ${DEFAULT_STR}, SYSTEM'`;
```